# Can you give a body only to either get or set in a property?

Tags: c#

```
    public int a{
        get;
        set{
            if (value <= b)
                a = value;
            if (value > b)
                a = b;
        }
    }
```

Is it possible in the above example to avoid giving a body to get, despite it being a simple return a;?

Comment: side note: `set` as it's implemented will cause `StackOverflowException`

Comment: Try to compile the code and see for yourself.

Comment: "despite it being a simple return a;" - that would cause a stack overflow, too...

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not.

And your `set` accessor calls itself ad infinitum.

If you had had `get { return a; }`, the getter would call itself forever as well. It is not an auto-property and no automatic backing field exists if you have a body on an accessor.

Comment: I'm a bit tired right now, so I didn't realize that. I'd need to store them into private fields, correct?

Comment: @Statharas.903 Yes, that is a usual thing to do. If you rename the property from `a` to `A`, then you could use the name `a` for the field. For example: `int a; public int A {
        get { return a; }
        set {
            if (value <= b)
            {    a = value; }
            else
               { a = b; }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just don't declare the `get` part.  This results in a write-only property (you can't use the [auto-implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) getter).

```
public int a {
    set {
        if (value <= b)
            _a = value;
        if (value > b)
            _a = b;
    }
}
```

If you still want to be able to get values, but don't want that exposed, you can make the get private or internal, e.g.

```
public int a {
    internal get {
        return _a;
    }
    set {
        if (value <= b)
            _a = value;
        if (value > b)
            _a = b;
    }
}
```

Either way, you cannot use the auto-implementation of `get` or `set` if you use a custom implementation of either.

Note: I changed your references to `a` to references to a backing field, `_a`, otherwise your code would loop forever.

Comment: Err... how would you then get the value?

Comment: You wouldn't.  It's called a write-only property, e.g. you may use it logic related to certain secure features.

Comment: But the OP said "avoid giving a body to get, despite it being a simple return a;" ie the get should be `get {return _a;}` and they are wondering if they can use auto-implemented style syntax to save writing that out.

Comment: Sure, I understand.  I feel this answer is helpful in that it provides all the options, and does make it clear you have to implement both or neither. You don't have to upvote.